# Overridden function working in activity but not working in fragment

Tags: android

Which function can be overridden in activity and which one in fragments.
As onKeyDown function overridden in fragment was not working while it was working after overriding it in the activity

Comment: you need to post your specific problem or code here, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#public-methods) and [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#public-methods) documentation. Methods that are defined as `final` are not overridable. If they don't have the world `final` then you can override them no problem.

Just make sure to also run super method, as some of them require that (you'd get exception for those that do if you don't)